# Managing course enrollment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have written some code to suspend someone's enrollment to a course. A course may have multiple presentations.

```
module Enrolments
  class Suspend
    attr_reader :enrolment, :responses, :comment, :user_id
    attr_writer :event_service, :suspend_enrolment_presentation_service

    def initialize
      @responses = []
    end

    def call(enrolment, user_id, comment)
      @enrolment = enrolment
      @user_id = user_id
      @comment = comment

      suspend_enrolment_presentations
      if all_enrolment_presentations_suspended?
        suspend_enrolment
        raise_suspended_enrolment_event
        create_enrolment_comment
      end
    end

    private

    attr_reader :response

    def suspend_enrolment_presentations
      enrolment.enrolment_presentations.each do |ep|
        @responses << suspend_enrolment_presentation_service.call(ep)
      end
    end

    def all_enrolment_presentations_suspended?
      @responses.all?{ |r| r[:success] }
    end

    def suspend_enrolment
      enrolment.status = 'Suspended'
      enrolment.save
    end

    def raise_suspended_enrolment_event
      event_service.call(enrolment)
    end

    def create_enrolment_comment
      EnrolmentComment.create(comment: comment, user_id: user_id, enrolment_id: enrolment.id)
    end

    def event_service
      @event_service ||= Events::Outgoing::Enrolments::SuspendedEnrolment.new
    end

    def suspend_enrolment_presentation_service
      @suspend_enrolment_presentation_service ||= Enrolments::EnrolmentPresentations::Suspend.new
    end
  end
end
```

The code is fairly straight forward. It has a couple of dependencies that are injected via `attr_writer`s when testing, otherwise they are instantiated when accessed.

I have heard/read a lot of issues regarding callbacks. The problem with this code is if I ever want to just suspend an enrollment and not raise an event or create a comment, I can't. Some ways to get around this are with the decorator pattern or I guess I could compose and object of all the services and manage everything in there.

I really strive for SRP and good design in my code. I would really appreciate any input on how I could improve this code. Should I be extracting the code to a higher level of abstraction and dealing with it one level up? What if running one piece of code depends on another passing? If I was to extract this out it would land up in my controller which is as high as I can go, unless I then extracted that into a form object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the service methods, initialise the values in the `initialize` method.  And then in a subclass set a service that doesn't actually do anything with the enrollment.

```
class Enrolments::Suspend
  ...
  def initialize
    @responses = []
    # get rid of the methods and set the services in the intitialiser
    @event_service ||= Events::Outgoing::Enrolments::SuspendedEnrolment.new
    @suspend_enrolment_presentation_service ||= Enrolments::EnrolmentPresentations::Suspend.new
  end
  ...
end

class EnrollmentWithoutEvent < Enrolments::Suspend
  ...
  def initialize
    super
    # do default config here
    @event_service ||= Events::DoNothing.new
  end
  ...
end
```

Or, you could create a subclass that overrides the `raise_suspended_enrolment_event` method:

```
class Enrolments::SuspendWithoutErrors < Enrolments::Suspend
  def raise_suspended_enrolment_event
    # change the implementation here
  end
end
```

Another options would be to use `class_attribute` for your service objects/procs:

```
class Enrolments::Suspend
  ...
  class_attribute :event_service, :suspend_enrolment_presentation_service
  ...
end
```

Then, when you subclass, you get set your services per class or instance and can  change/add the services on any sub-classes or instances of sub-classes.  Have a look at [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute) for how it works.  This method means that you can create classes with specific services, and when you instantiate the class, the instances also use the same services.

For example:

```
class Enrolments::Suspend
  ...
  class_attribute :event_service, :suspend_enrolment_presentation_service

  # create the services used for this class
  self.event_service = proc {|enrollment| ... }
  self.suspend_enrolment_presentation_service = proc {|e| ... }
end

class SuspendWithoutError < Enrolments::Suspend
  # override one of the services but keep the rest
  self.suspend_enrolment_presentation_service = proc {|e| ... }
end
```

The final option is to use actual methods:

```
class Enrolments::Suspend
  ...

  def event_service(enrollment)
    ...
  end

  def suspend_enrolment_presentation_service(enrollment)
    ...
  end
end
```

This allows any sub-classes to override the methods.

Comment: Thanks for the review. It definitely gave me some options. Just a couple of notes. The service methods are written in such a way to allow for easy dependency injection while testing - this could have been done in the constructor, but I prefer this method. Regarding the use of inheritance, I am not a fan of the way you have implemented it since any child classes still seem to be dependent on the actual callback. If I ended up deleting the event_service class I would need to change both the `Enrolments::Suspend` and `SuspendWithoutError`. I should only need to change one place. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

As the original class was breaking SRP in my opinion, I decided to split up the class into two classes. One handles the coordination of things that need to happen when a suspension happens. This allows me to contain just the actual suspension logic to Enrolments::Suspend and any other required callbacks were put into the coordinator. This way each class should have only one reason to change.

```
module Enrolments
  class SuspendCoordinator
    attr_reader :enrolment, :comment
    attr_writer :event_service, :suspend_enrolment_service

    def call(enrolment, comment)
      @enrolment = enrolment
      @comment = comment

      if suspend_enrolment
        raise_suspended_enrolment_event
        create_enrolment_comment
      end
    end

    private

    attr_reader :responses

    def suspend_enrolment
      suspend_enrolment_service.call(enrolment)
    end

    def raise_suspended_enrolment_event
      event_service.call(enrolment)
    end

    def create_enrolment_comment
      EnrolmentComment.create(comment: comment, user_id: RequestRegistry.current_user.id, enrolment_id: enrolment.id)
    end

    def suspend_enrolment_service
      @suspend_enrolment_service ||= Enrolments::Suspend.new
    end

    def event_service
      @event_service ||= Events::Outgoing::Enrolments::SuspendedEnrolment.new
    end
  end
end

module Enrolments
  class Suspend
    attr_reader :enrolment, :responses, :comment, :user_id
    attr_writer :suspend_enrolment_presentation_service

    def initialize
      @responses = []
    end

    def call(enrolment)
      @enrolment = enrolment

      suspend_enrolment_presentations
      suspend_enrolment if all_enrolment_presentations_suspended?
    end

    private

    attr_reader :response

    def suspend_enrolment_presentations
      enrolment.enrolment_presentations.each do |ep|
        @responses << suspend_enrolment_presentation_service.call(ep)
      end
    end

    def suspend_enrolment
      enrolment.status = 'Suspended'
      enrolment.save
    end

    def all_enrolment_presentations_suspended?
      @responses.all?{ |r| r[:success] }
    end

    def suspend_enrolment_presentation_service
      @suspend_enrolment_presentation_service ||= Enrolments::EnrolmentPresentations::Suspend.new
    end
  end
end
```